# getting wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure

Tags: plsql

I am trying to call a procedure using below code and getting

> `wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure`

The issue could be with the record type being passed as parameter , but I couldn't see any issue with that .

```
    DECLARE
       p_status          VARCHAR2 (4) := 'S';
       p_id              NUMBER := 123456;
       p_py_id           NUMBER := 513;
       p_type            NUMBER := 1;
       p_date_time       DATE   := TO_DATE ('10/01/2018 23:50:42', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
       p_os_pay          NUMBER := 0;
       p_ind             VARCHAR2 (2) := 'Y';
       p_confirm         VARCHAR2 (2) := 'Y';
       p_year            NUMBER := 2018;
       p_reason          VARCHAR2 (5) := NULL;
       p_currrpay        NUMBER := 1517;

       p_details        pkg.g_r_type;

    BEGIN
       p_details.pro_code := 'AB';
       p_details.inst_type := '1';
       p_details.pay_date := TO_DATE ('19/10/2016 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
       p_details.pay_amt := 5000;
       p_details.h_code := 'ABCD';
       p_details.pay_ind := 'N';
       p_details.c_code := 123456;
       p_details.c_year := 8;


       pkg.procedure_info (          p_status,
                                     p_id,
                                     p_py_id,
                                     p_type,
                                     p_date_time,
                                     p_os_pay,
                                     p_ind,
                                     p_confirm,
                                     p_year,
                                     p_reason,
                                     p_details,
                                     p_currrpay
                         );
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
    END;
    /
```

Below is the package description :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package pkg
as
  type g_r_type is record (
    pro_code             varchar2 (2)
   ,inst_type           varchar2 (1)
   ,pay_date             date
   ,pay_amt           number (13, 2)
   ,h_code               varchar2 (4)
   ,pay_ind              varchar2 (1)
   ,c_code               number(6)
   ,c_year               number(2)
  );


  procedure procedure_info (
                            p_status             in   varchar2
                           ,p_id                 in   number
                           ,p_py_id              in   number
                           ,p_type               in   number
                           ,p_date_time          in   date
                           ,p_os_pay             in   number
                           ,p_ind                in   varchar2
                           ,p_confirm            in   varchar2
                           ,p_year               in   number
                           ,p_failure_reason     in   varchar2
                           ,p_details            in   g_r_type
                           ,p_currrpay           in       number  
  );
end pkg;
/
```

I have cross checked the datatypes, length and number of arguments , but couldn't find the issue.

Comment: The code runs well for me. Are you sure you did exactly what you posted? Did you use the same user to create the package and call the procedure?

Comment: It must be something related with what you do inside the `procedure_info`. You probably are doing some incorrect assignments... Can you post the body?

Comment: You need to post the package body. The question is unanswerable without it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package scripts end with a `/` at the very end of the text file, as the first char of the line (and last non blank).

If your package was created successfully, you should get a message:

> `package created successfully`

Then if your package's *Body* is:

> `package body created successfully`

To make sure your package is correctly created on the database:

This query should help:

```
Select * from all_source where name='PKG';
```

And for the body:

```
Select * 
  from all_source 
 where name='PKG'
   and type='PACKAGE BODY';
```

Comment: The package was created fine for me , the problem I am having is when trying to call the package .